# Eclipse, how to combine 2 editions

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I'm using the PHP edition of Eclipse, but was told that I also need the Java EE edition. I'd like to install them both in the same install (single launch) and not have to open 2 editions in parallel. Is there a way to easily get this done? I'm new to eclipse, so detailed instructions are welcome.

Comment: When you say JEE edition, are you talking about the Java Edition?

Comment: There are 2 Java editions, 1 is the standard Java edition, and another one called the JEE edition which has a few more plugins. See this chart http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it the other way around: first install [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) and then add the **PHP Development Tools** (PDT) from the update site (instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation)).

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty straightforward. Download one edition, then have it install the plugins comprising the other. This is done via *Install New Software* in the *Help* menu; first time out you will need to hit the *Add* button and tell it about the *update site URL* for the plugin set you want to install. You can find the update site URLs via the main Eclipse website.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Java EE version is a superset of the PHP one, at least for things mentioned in this chart...

***http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages***

So, I would start with Java EE. Check the plugins and features and use the Help->Install dialog to add any new plugins you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I would start with the ["Eclipse IDE for Java Developers"](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and then add those plugins needed for PHP.  From this [chart](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages), it looks like you'll need to add [Webtools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) and the [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/).